# Matlab only show certain elements in legend

Tags: matlab

I am trying to plot some data as follows:

```
figure(2);
l = plot(1:50,data_a(:,2),1:50, data_a(:,2), 'b*');
set(l,'Color','red');

hold on;
lb = plot(1:50,data_b(:,2),1:50, data_b(:,2), 'b*');
set(lb, 'Color', 'blue');

hold on;
lc = plot(1:50,data_c(:,2),1:50, data_c(:,2), 'b*');
set(lc, 'Color', 'green');

hold on; 
ld = plot(1:50,data_d(:,2),1:50, data_d(:,2), 'b*');
set(ld, 'Color', 'cyan');

legend([l,lb,lc,ld], 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
```

If I just use

```
legend('show')
```

This will also include the points drawn by the text() function, which I don't want. Hence why in the last line I am specifying I only want elements l, lb, lc and ld (the plots) to be included in the legend.

This is consistent with the instructions [given on the MathWorks site](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/legend.html#bt6s_3t).

However, it returns an error as:

```
Error using legend (line 120)
Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.

Error in visualizer (line 33)
legend([l,lb,lc,ld], 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
```

Any advice?

Comment: Your handles are not scalars. You're plotting two things with each call to `plot`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your `plot` calls plot two things, hence the handles returned are 2-by-1 vectors. You can try this – just use the first element of each handle vector:

```
legend([l(1),lb(1),lc(1),ld(1)], 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
```

However, I'm not sure why you seem to be plotting the same data twice just to color the line and the marker. If you fix that, then your handles will be scalars, and the legend entries will look correct. Something like this maybe:

```
figure(2);
l = plot(1:50, data_a(:,2), 'r-*');

hold on;
lb = plot(1:50, data_b(:,2), 'b-*');

hold on;
lc = plot(1:50, data_c(:,2), 'g-*');

hold on; 
ld = plot(1:50, data_d(:,2), 'c-*');

legend([l,lb,lc,ld], 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
```

Or the slightly different:

```
figure(2);
l = plot(1:50, data_a(:,2), 'b*');
set(l,'Color','r');

hold on;
lb = plot(1:50, data_b(:,2), 'b*');
set(lb,'Color','b');

hold on;
lc = plot(1:50, data_c(:,2), 'b*');
set(lc,'Color','g');

hold on; 
ld = plot(1:50, data_d(:,2), 'b*');
set(ld,'Color','c');

legend([l,lb,lc,ld], 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
```

Answer (score 0):

The handle can not be more than a scalar value. So you cannot assign a plot including more than a curve to a handle and use that handle to set the legend.
Check what I have done for 'l4' in the following example:

```
x = 1:0.1:10;
y = sin(x);
z= cos(x);
w = y + z;

l1 = plot(x,y,'bo'); hold on
l2 = plot(x,z,'bo'); hold on
l3 = plot(x,w,'bo'); hold on

l4 = plot(x,y+1,x,z+1,'+');


set(l1,'Color','red');
set(l2,'Color','blue');
set(l3,'Color','green');

set(l4,'Color','black');

legend([l1,l2,l3, l4(1), l4(2)],'A','B','C','D','E')
```

[image]